# How to handle events when application gets killed in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to handle the ios application when it is killed or any way to open my app programatically in ios 9.

Comment: why down voting my question. It is possible in android. Noobs will surely down vote it.

Answer (score 2):

No.

When your app is killed, that is equivalent to being force quit.  There is no signal or notification.

There is no way to cause the system to open your app automatically because that would be a security risk as well as being really annoying to the user.

You can use push notifications and/or extensions to make your app's presence known more to the user.